# What is MM routine function that does the opposite of what N does?

Tags: functions

I would like to convert these numbers to their closest fractional equivalent to see if there is any pattern linking them e.g they are all mutiple of some basic fractional number.

The numbers are:

```
1.9300728018940605
2.6716041047068817
1.6778839380872763
1.727365137695202
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: `Rationalize`??

Comment: It is mentioned in `N's` documentation.

Comment: @ Szabolcs. Swift and efficient answers like always! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually a simultaneous diophantine approximation might be wanted here. That's somewhat beyond what Rationalize can deliver.

Comment: @Daniel, well, the old ``NumberTheory`Rationalize`​`` had `AffineRationalize[]` and `ProjectiveRationalize[]` for that​…

Comment: @J. M. I know, and I miss those at times.